# Aisément vs facilement?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Is there any difference in the connotation or usage between these two words, which are both translations for *easily* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ils sont synonymes. Pas de différence de sens.

*Facilement* est le plus utilisé. *Aisément* est un tout petit peu plus stylé.

*facilement* a un autre emploi : *au moins*. *[Il mettra facilement deux heures pour faire ce travail.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/facilement)*

Quant aux adjectifs:

- *facile* a donné l'expression *trop facile*, et un dérivé familier *fastoche*.
- *aisé* a un autre sens: qui a des moyens (financiers), sans être *riche*.

*à l'aise* signifie: *commodément*, *sans gêne*.

[voir aussi le CNRTL](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/ais%C3%A9ment)